# How do i check if a user wrote the command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this

```
await ctx.send("Which inventory do you want to access?")
        await ctx.send("Mining, Collecting, Farming, Fishing or Fighting?")

        def check(user):
            if user == ctx.author:
                # Idk what to do here
                pass

        type_check = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

        if type_check.content.lower() == "mining":
            await ctx.send("You chose Mining!")

        if type_check.content.lower() == "collecting":
            await ctx.send("You chose Collecting!")

        if type_check.content.lower() == "farming":
            await ctx.send("You chose Farming!")

        if type_check.content.lower() == "fishing":
            await ctx.send("You chose Fishing!")

        if type_check.content.lower() == "fighting":
            await ctx.send("You chose Fighting!")
```

And I need to check if a user wrote the message and if they did it would await ctx send the thing

Comment: Can you describe the business problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: i just want to check if the user ran the command because otehr people can open the inventory

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, maybe by better explain why do you need to monitor the user interaction with the system and what are the constraints or considerations to take in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check func must return a boolean, also the argument passed is a `discord.Message` object not a user

```py
def check(message):
    if message.author == ctx.author:
        return True
```

or

```py
# This is a better way
def check(message):
    return message.author == ctx.author
```

btw a better solution for those if statements is checking if they're in a list:

```py
inv_type = type_check.content.lower()
if inv_type in ['mining', 'collecting', 'farming', 'fishing', 'fighting']:
    await ctx.send(f"You chose {inv_type}!")
```

Comment: I'd like to add that you could also add this into your check function with `return message.content.lower() in ['mining', 'collecting', 'farming', 'fishing', 'fighting']` to keep waiting until you received a valid response.